# unable to create sandbox test account on paypal

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway

I'm trying to sandbox test account. but after filling all the fields, when I click on submit button, it nothing is happening.

It keep me on same page, and also doesn't showing any validation error.

This is my form.

[image]

I have followed the same steps
Step to [**create sandbox test account**](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/sb_create-accounts/)

Comment: Jaipur is not a valid city in Virginia, have you considered using valid information?

Comment: It's not showing Indian city and State. then what should I fill there. I'm from india.

Comment: open that link, Then click on signUp. you will be redirected to [this link](https://www.paypal.com/webapps/merchantboarding/webflow/unifiedflow?execution=e5s2)